# SEO problems using jQuery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created a modal window with load function with links inside the modal window. The crawler is unable to read and index those links. I need a way to make crawler index those links.

I see websites using angular js ranking such as https://www.dailyobjects.com/designer-cases (This website has a similar modal window) ranking on top in Google Search and I google never reads or index angular js made pages.

They managed to crawl it, so there must be a way to crawl a javascript modal window which I have made.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please provide your code for your modal window

Comment: add your code, and probably depends if the content in your modal is static or not.

Answer (score -2):

Angular uses Server-Side Rendering(SSR) to fix SEO issues. Just read more on this.